# DataRow need to be casted before linq operations . Why?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

DataRowCollection : InternalDataCollectionBase

InternalDataCollectionBase : ICollection, IEnumerable

So , DataRowCollection indirectly inherites IEnumerable.
Generally , If a class inherites IEnumerable we can apply linq operations . 
But in  DataRowCollection this fails . Why?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Linq extension methods (from [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) operate on a generic [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather than the non-generic [System.Collections.IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that InternalDataCollectionBase implements. That's why you use the `Cast` (or `OfType`) extension method to turn your `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: I agree to this .Still, I have a few doubts. DataRowCollection is from COM dll (i.e) System.Data .To extend the functionality of COM dll to support linq ,System.Collections.IEnumerable is used .Is this correct ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. DataRowCollection and System.Collections.IEnumerable have been around since .NET 1.1, but System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable was only introduced in .NET 2.0, so DataRowCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<DataRow>, only IEnumerable. Linq requires IEnumerable<T> to be implemented, so doesn't work with DataRowCollection. Using Cast or OfType will give you an IEnumerable<T> from an IEnumerable, so they can be used with DataRowCollection to give you an IEnumerable<DataRow> which can then be used with the Linq extension methods.